# How to change form action when a 'preview' button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, action

I am trying to get a different page, `preview.php` to show when the Preview Button is clicked, by changing the action of the form.
The preview button should lead to another page where I can view the inputs from the file and maybe have options to submit or go back.

The other buttons, submit and clear work however the preview button does not seem to be working. It stays on the same page even after clicking the button.

As a test I put in some alerts. 'here1' and 'here2' alerts work, but 'here3' alert does not work, making me believe the changeAct() function is not reached.
How can I fix this so the form action can be changed?

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('blog-btn');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const btn = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!btn) {
    return;
  } else {
    processClick(event.target.id)
  }
});

function processClick(id) {
    
    alert("Id is "+ id);
    
    if(id == "pre")
    {   
        alert("here 1");
        document.getElementById('pre').addEventListener('click', changeAct);
        alert("here 2");
   }

}

function changeAct()
{
    alert("here 3");
    document.getElementById('frm1').action="preview.php";
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1" name="post_form" action="addEntry.php" method="post">
        <div id="blog-btn">
            <!--Post & Clear Form Buttons-->
            <button type="button" value="Preview" id="pre" >PREVIEW</button>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub">SUBMIT</button>
            <button type="reset" value="Reset" id="clear">CLEAR</button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Seems ok to me: https://jsfiddle.net/z3aqnsty/ . All the buttons show the alerts, including the "here" alert when the Preview button is pressed. It's unclear what exactly the issue is. Create a [mre] of your issue and [edit] your question when it's ready. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: If you are hoping that the page will be redirected to `preview.php` when you click the `preview` button your lofic is a little flawed. A regular button is, by default a `submit` button but when you assign it the `type='button'` it will no longer submit the form. In your javascript logic rather than reassign the form action and then register a new event handler perhaps you just want to submit the form at that stage programmatically?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thanks for the reply. I do not want to submit the form when the preview button is clicked, hence putting the `type=button`. Rather, it should redirect me to another page where I can view the form inputs, *before* deciding wether to submit.

Comment: Oh, OK. Nothing in the above suggests that but I think I understand. You could submit as I suggested to the `preview` page and on that page rebuild the form with the real destination action attribute on the form. If all looks good there then submit?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for replying. I have restructured my code and question so hopefully it makes things clearer

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thanks again! I have changed the type to submit as you suggested and it is working better than before!

Comment: @FionaAmpofo sorry I missed the distinction between the here1 and here, I should have paid more attention. If you look in the Console in the browser there's an error because `id` isn't an element and therefore you can't add an event listener to it. You'd need to write `document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', changeAct);` . But even then it would only run the second time you clicked on the button (and subsequently) because you're not adding the listener until the first click occurs. That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Maybe just actually call changeAct directly from there?

Comment: Demo of what I mean: 1) https://jsfiddle.net/crksL0y5/1/ , 2) https://jsfiddle.net/crksL0y5/2/

Comment: `Rather, it should redirect me to another page where I can view the form inputs, before deciding wether to submit`....why not just use JS to generate the preview within the same page? or if generating the preview involves doing something only the server can do, such as running a SQL query, then maybe use AJAX to do that and return the result and show it? Then a final decision on submission can be made without redirecting. But it's just an idea to think about, not essential.